# What is my current octave range, can it go much farther, and how can I increase it?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

My lowest note is a D3, and my highest note is an F6. I am a 14 year old female. I play clarinet, so I am often exercising my lungs even when I am not singing. My dad has more of an average range, but my mom used to have a range of 4-5 octaves. I think I am a mezzo soprano, I am just not certain about how many octaves I have.

Could anyone tell me what my range is and how I can improve it?

P.S. I have had a cough for almost 2 years now that seems asthmatic and may be influenced by allergies. If I could get rid of it, how would that affect my range?

Comment: There are a lot of questions with good answers about extending your range. Here's a few. http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/how-to-extend-the-range-of-your-voice?rq=1, http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/finding-and-improving-singing-range-and-power?rq=1. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely extend my vocal range?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/804/how-can-i-safely-extend-my-vocal-range)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer all your questions is to take some singing lessons from a qualified voice teacher, or at least to do some singing for your school or church or community choir director. There is absolutely no way that anybody can properly answer these questions of yours by reading your short written description of your voice.

In addition, if you are interested in pursuing some singing lessons, your voice and your range will probably "open up" and you may develop the ability to sing in different, wider registers than what you can do now. However, you are quite young; serious singing lessons are sometimes best left until you are older. You would need to consult with a qualified teacher about that.

As far as your chronic cough or asthma symptoms, your singing would certainly improve if your cough went away, so you may need some medical help there.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you've already made a lot of progress in the breath support training.

Of course a private voice teacher would be ideal.  If that's not feasible for you at this point, find a choir to sing in (church, school, community center, etc.).  You can learn a lot from a good choir director.  Also, the director may be willing to coach you, even if it's only once every month or two.

One's range might expand through the right sort of singing practice.

It sounds like you've got quite a large range -- slightly over three octaves.

It would be a very good idea to clear up your respiratory problems.  You could start with your primary care doctor.  You might find it helpful to see a specialist, but you might be able to make some good progress with just the primary.

Untreated respiratory problems can result in permanent damage to the voice.